# "hash trail", iterative hash function that can be traced back along many steps

Tags: hash

What are some examples of an iterative hash function, where permutations along

```
A ---> B ---> C ---> D
```

can be compared, for example D/B, to see if D is a trail from B, and possibly the distance in steps from  C to D

Comment: I guess you can use any hash function, you just try to hash B Until you get D and count the number.

Answer (score 2):

SHA-256 or any at least as wide unbroken cryptographic hash will do, if the elements can be that wide (except the first `A` which is unconstrained). With a $w$-bit ideal hash, probability of entering a cycle in $n\ge1$ steps are $p<n^2/2^{w+1}$, by the [Birthday problem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/39644/555). E.g. $w=256$, $n\le2^{100}$ gives residual odds of entering a cycle $p<2^{-57}$, and that's good enough in practice.

Things are not quite as easy when $w$ must be smaller; e.g. for $w=160$. In this case, we want a hash function less likely to iterate than random; that's not a common beast (to be continued after thinking about it).