# Is Paillier secure from known plaintext attack for single character message?

Tags: public-key, cryptanalysis, homomorphic-encryption, known-plaintext-attack, paillier

Assuming I have three messages m1,m2,m3 where m1=m2=m3=1 and I compute c1,c2 and c3.

Does that mean that c1=c2=c3 in cipher-text from ?
If not, how many times can I encrypt a message m=1 and still produce a unique cipher-text ?

if not possible, can I solve the problem by putting Zeros as padding and still use the additive property ? (e.g. m1=01...m2=001 and m3=0001 and when I calculate x=c1+c2+c3 the decrypted result D{x}=3)

I just started working with cryptography, so please be understanding. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, [Paillier encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem) is secure from known plaintext attack (for single-character message, and any other supported message size). With high likelihood, three ciphertexts $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ for the same plaintext will be different.

When using public modulus $n$, each Paillier encryption draws a uniformly random number $r$ in range $[0,n)$ (some descriptions say $[0,n^2)$ but it turns out only $r\bmod n$ has an influence on the cryptogram; and in some descriptions it's added $r$ is coprime with $n$, but that's overwhelmingly likely for secure choice of $n$, thus can be omitted). Different $r$ will lead to different cryptograms $c=g^m\cdot r^n\bmod n^2$.

For proper implementation, by the [birthday problem 101](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/39644/555), the probability is about $k^2/2n$ that among $k$ ciphertexts for the same plaintext, any two are equal. For security against factoring, $n$ must have some thousand bits, thus said probability is entirely negligible for any feasible $k$ and secure choice of $n$. It is much more likely that whatever generates $r$ gets defective, and hickups, leading to identical ciphertexts.

Note: Pailler encryption is homomorphic only for messages that are straight integers $m$. Padding with zeroes on the left can't change $m$ if the homomorphic property must remain.