# Derivation of birthday paradox probability

Tags: birthday-attack, probability

I am trying to come up with an explanation of the probability of birthday collision.

$P$(no collision among t people) = $(1− \frac{1}{365}) · (1-\frac{2}{365}) ··· (1-\frac{t-1}{365})$

> For one person, the probability of no collision is 1, which is trivial
>   since a single birthday cannot collide with anyone else’s. For the
>   second person, the probability of no collision is 364 over 365, since
>   there is only one day, the birthday of the first person, to collide
>   with:
>
> $P$(no collision among 2 people) = $(1− \frac{1}{365})$
>
> If a third person joins the party, he or she can collide with both of
>   the people already there, hence:
>
> $P$(no collision among 2 people) = $(1− \frac{1}{365})·(1−\frac{2}{365})$

While it is clear how we get the probability of collision for 2 people, it is not intuitive to me that how we get the probability of collision between 3 people. I'd expect the probability would be $(1−\frac{2}{365})$. For example, when you roll the dice, the probability of $6$ is $\frac{1}{6}$, and the probability for 5 or 6 is $\frac{2}{6}$. It is not $\frac{1}{6}$·$\frac{2}{6}$ which seems to be the case in birthday collisions.

I'd appreciate an answer with an intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability becomes more intuitive when one pictures the $t$ persons entering one by one in the room.

Before the first person enters, there's no collision/coincidence of birth-date, thus probability of no collision is $P_0=1$.

When the first person enters, there can't be a collision/coincidence of birthdate, probability of no collision is $P_1=1$.

When the second person enters, there is one chance in $365$ that his/her birthday is the same as the first person's birthdate, thus the probability of no collision is $P_2=1-\frac1{365}$.

When the third person enters, either
- there was a collision at the previous stage, and then the probability of no collision is $0$;
- or there was no collision at the previous stage, thus there was $2$ persons with different birth-dates in the room, and the probability that the third person has one of their birth-dates is $2$ in $365$, thus the probability of no collision is $1-\frac2{365}$.
The total probability of no collision after the third person enters is obtained by adding these two probabilities weighted by the probability conditioning them. We thus have $P_3=(1-P_2)\,0+P_2\,\bigl(1-\frac2{365}\bigr)$, thus $P_3=\bigl(1-\frac1{365}\bigr)\bigl(1-\frac2{365}\bigr)$

The same reasoning gives $P_{i+1}=(1-P_i)\,0+P_i\bigl(1-\frac i{365}\bigr)$, that is $P_{i+1}=P_i\bigl(1-\frac i{365}\bigr)$.

From which it comes $P_t=\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^{t-1}\,\Bigl(1-\frac i{365}\Bigr)$.

For derivation of formulas used in a cryptographic context where the numbers are huge, see my [*Birthday problem for cryptographic hashing, 101*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/39644/555).
Note: $P$, $t$, and $365$ here are $q$, $n$ and $k$ there.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to write it out using the chain rule of probability theory as:

\begin{align*}
  \Pr[\text{no collision among 2}]
    &= 1 - \frac{1}{365} \\
  \Pr[\text{no collision among 3}]
    &= \Pr[\text{no collision with 3rd, and no collision among first 2}] \\
    &= \Pr[\text{no collision with 3rd}
            \mid \text{no collision among 2}] \\
    &\qquad \cdot \Pr[\text{no collision among 2}] \\
    &= \biggl(1 - \frac{2}{365}\biggr) \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{365}\biggr),
\end{align*}

and so on with $\Pr[\text{no collision among 4}]$, $\Pr[\text{no collision among 5}]$, *etc.*

In particular, $1 - \frac{n - 1}{365}$ is the probability that the $n^{\mathit{th}}$ person has a different birthday from the $n - 1$ *prior* persons, *given* that the $n - 1$ prior persons all have distinct birthdays—that is, $1 - \frac{n-1}{365}$ is $\Pr[\text{no collision with $n^{\mathit{th}}$}$ $\mid$ $\text{no collisions among $n - 1$}]$, but you read it as $\Pr[\text{no collision among $n$}]$.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back I did a detailed study of this problem.
So the problem was
"How many people(***n***) you need in a room such that ***m*** of them sharing birthday is 50%.?"
We know that for **m=2**, we need **n=23** people such that probability of any two of them sharing birthday is 50%.

Suppose we have find **n**, such that probability of **m=3** people share birthday is 50%.
We will calculate how 3 people out of n **doesn’t** share a birthday and subtract this probability from 1.

- All n people have different birthday.
- 1 pair (2 people) share birthday and the rest n-2 have distinct birthday.

  - Number of ways 1 pair (2 people) can be chosen = C(n, 2)
  - This pair can take any of 365 days
  - For these n-2 people they can pick 365–1 birthdays.
- Next we make 2 group of 2 people and rest n-4 have distinct birthday.
  Like this we can recursively create more groups and find all possible combination where **m** people doesn't share birthday.

https://medium.com/@c0D3M/birthday-paradox-3fd2f0f6c5a0

Comment: This is like the advertisement of your medium article. Here another [Understanding the Birthday Paradox](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-the-birthday-paradox/)

Comment: sorry about that, I am newbie, so one has to write/copy instead of link ?

Comment: I cannot say a copy but at least a proper answer?